# jQuery v1.10+ val() creates empty option if none exists

Tags: jquery

Recently updated to jQuery v1.12 and found that it sets `<select>` elements to a nonexistant option if one doesn't exist, instead of gracefully falling back to unsetting the value as it did previously.

Here is the behavior I'm used to (pre v1.10):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("select").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">something 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">something 2</option>
</select>
<button>reset</button>
```

And here is how v1.10+ behaves:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("select").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">something 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">something 2</option>
</select>
<button>reset</button>
```

**Is this a bug or is this the intended behavior?**

I read through the [**changelog**](https://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/24/jquery-1-10-0-and-2-0-1-released/) and don't see any specific mention of this change but finding it rather disruptive.

*(Please note: I am **not** looking for workarounds and as noted in the comments, I've already changed my app to use `$('select').prop("selectedIndex", 0).change();`)*

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you set dropdown to non-existent option, if you want to reset it?

Comment: Parts my of application have code like `$('select').val('');` which previously would reset the select elements in a form.  Now it fails and I've updated it to `$('select').prop("selectedIndex", 0).change();` which works fine but I didn't expect to have to scour my code for this when I updated jQuery.

Comment: @sinisake - I've updated my question - I just had *"abc"* in there to demonstrate that the behavior is not limited to setting an empty value - in retrospect it makes my question a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand...interesting...but, one way or another, you have to change code (hope there was no too much selects:))

Comment: Seems like the kind of change that should be documented... if it's not a bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery automatically setting it to the first or default option was a bug which was fixed post jQuery 1.10+

See this link : https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13514

Comment: so let me get this straight, the entire jQuery library was changed to conform with the inconsistent behavior of IE9?  Lol.. well if that isn't the stupidest thing I've heard all week.  But thanks for the link... I do believe that answers my question.